# How to generate xml and format it from object in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Here I am trying to format XML from a list and I am not getting the proper format. Here is my code:

```
protected void GenerateXml(string url, List<string> listitems)  //generateXml
{
    XNamespace nsXhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
    XNamespace nsSitemap = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    XNamespace nsImage = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1";
    var sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", ""));

    var urlSet =
        new XElement(
            nsSitemap + "urlset",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", nsSitemap),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "image", nsXhtml),
            from urlNode in listitems
            select 
                new XElement(
                    nsSitemap + "url",
                    new XElement(nsSitemap + "loc", url),
                    new XElement(nsSitemap + "image",
                    new XElement(nsSitemap + "imageloc", urlNode))));

    sitemap.Add(urlSet);
    sitemap.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Static/sitemaps/Sitemap-image.xml"));
}
```

... and getting the format like this:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/intl/cars/new-models/the-new-s90</loc>
    <image> 
      <imageloc>http://example.com/static/images/volvo-logo-scaled.png</imageloc>
    </image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/intl/cars/new-models/the-new-s90</loc>
    <image>
      <imageloc>http://assets.example.com/intl/~/media/images/galleries/new-cars/packshots/small/allnew_xc90-side_2.png</imageloc>
    </image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

But I need in this format:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url> 
</urlset>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want `image:image` nodes, why are you doing `new XElement(nsSitemap + "image"` rather than `new XElement(nsImage + "image"` ?

Comment: And if you want multiple `image` within the `url`, you'll need to move the `new XElement(nsSitemap + "url"` outside the `from`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to properly handling the multiple nested elements, you never assigned the `image` prefix to the elements that are supposed to have them, you continue to use the global namespace:

```
new XElement(nsSitemap + "image",
   new XElement(nsSitemap + "imageloc", urlNode)
```

`nsSitemap` should be `nsImage`, and "imageloc" should be "loc".

A couple minor tweaks to your code will get you what you're looking for:

```
protected void GenerateXml(string url, List<string> listitems)  //generateXml
{

    XNamespace nsSitemap = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    XNamespace nsImage = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1";

    var sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", ""));

    var urlSet = new XElement(nsSitemap + "urlset",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", nsSitemap),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "image", nsImage),
        new XElement(nsSitemap + "url",
        new XElement(nsSitemap + "loc", url),
        from urlNode in listitems
        select new XElement(nsImage + "image",
               new XElement(nsImage + "loc", urlNode)
           )));
        sitemap.Add(urlSet);          sitemap.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Static/sitemaps/Sitemap-image.xml"));
}
```

Notice the following changes:

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "image", nsImage);
```

This sets the namespace correctly to mach your expected output.

```
new XElement(nsImage + "image",
new XElement(nsImage + "loc", urlNode)
```

This sets the `image` prefix correctly.

Notice how "loc" and "url" were moved to before the `from` query.

The above code results in the following output XML:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```